# Format (rewrap) Markdown document to adhere to given line width

Tags: format, markdown

I have a long Markdown document with lines longer than 80 characters. I would like it to adhere to a style guide prescribing lines no longer than 80 characters (with exceptions of code snippets and tables). Is there a tool an editor or an editor extension reformat (rewrap) the document while respecting Markdown syntax?

Comment: Does this help?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25173/how-can-i-wrap-text-at-a-certain-column-size

Comment: Not really - it ignores the syntax and would wrap code segments and tables which I want to avoid. Thank you for suggesting though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prettier (https://prettier.io), which is available as a plug-in for many editors, seems like a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the file in Emacs, select all content (bound to `C-x h`), call [`fill-paragraph`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillParagraph) (bound to `M-q`). The Markdown syntax is respected as long as [markdown-mode](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode) is installed.

You can have it wrap at any given column by setting the variable `fill-column`, which can be done by evaluating `(setq fill-column 80)`, or calling `M-x set-fill-column RET 80`, or typing `C-x f 80 RET`.

Save the file by calling save-buffer, bound to `C-x C-s`.

Full incantation: `C-x f 80 RET C-x h M-q C-x C-s`.